# js / jquery function call order not reflected in result

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT:

Alright, to help resolve this, I've put up the example online:
http://lodge323.com/test/index.html

The example works as intended, but it doesn't have the content that I want on it. Note that this apparently only happens on FF13 and not IE9.

Steps to recreate the problem:
-Ctrl+F5 to reload the page (overriding cache).
-Using Firebug (addon for FF), change 1.jpg to head.gif
-Click on the Inventory menu tab on the right

Notice how there's a gap between the menu and the bottom which doesn't happen if 1.jpg is used. So question is, how can I get that gif image to work properly with the page?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, so here's my guess as to what your problem is: does `loadSidebar` seems to execute before `loadContent`?

Comment: Why are you storing a url in an element's `id`? (`$(elm).attr(attr)` expands to `$(this).attr('id')`)

Comment: @Eric I realize that. I'm using id because if I use href on <a>, when the element is clicked, it loads the page immediately. Using <a id="foo" href="#"> allowed me to have the functionality I wanted without extra code. If you have a better way, go ahead and post it!

Comment: While putting data in the `id` is always a bad idea, there's nothing wrong with creating new attributes, of the form `data-####`, eg `data-ajaxloads`. However, in this case making it work with `href` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous.

Instead of calling loadSidebar after loadContent, pass it as a callback to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
        loadContent('#ContentDiv', this, '.tabs a', 'id', loadSidebar);
    });
});

function loadContent(divTarget, elm, selector, attr, callback) {
    $(divTarget).load($(elm).attr(attr) + ' #ContentLoad', callback);
}
```

This will call loadSidebar, when the content has finished loading, instead of immediately after it starts loading.

Check out [Understanding Callback Functions in Javascript](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/). It might help you understand why the callback is needed.

**Edit**

As Eric pointed out it the comments you are also storing a url in an id. You should instead store it in the `href` attribute of the anchor. Then you can just return false from your click handler to avoid the entire page being loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
        loadContent('#ContentDiv', this, '.tabs a', 'href', loadSidebar);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm still having the same problem, but a few other things have been fixed/improved- thanks. The code works for some pages, but not for others.